# Windows VC++ compiler allows an odd way of c style casting (or it may not be casting??)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

***I know it is always better to avoid c style casting in C++ program.***

The below is a very simple code, which compiles good on windows `VC++ compiler` (also runs successfully. Printed the number). But fails to compile on `C++ - GCC` and `C++ - Clang`.

```
char c = 'A';
int num = unsigned char(c);
```

Yes, it is not a standard way of casting, so there is no wrong in compile time failure in `GCC` or `Clang`.

But Why `VC++ (Microsoft Visual Studio)` is able to compile and execute successfully?

Is it really a **casting concept** or **some other programming concept** allows it to work in `VC++`?

As it is working in `VC++`, what could be the **rough implementation on windows side**, to make the above piece of code working? *(Rough guess also fine.... just to understand how they (Microsoft windows) handled it.)*

***Note: The `VC compiler` (c compiler) fails to compile above piece of code. The interesting thing is with `VC++ compiler`, doing good both compile and run.***

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RetiredNinja.... I am trying to understand, why the code is working only on visual studio (vC++)?

Comment: What is the XY problem?
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: So Stack overflow do not give answers for such questions?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a c-style cast expression, it is specific to c++, though not very used. It is called functional style cast.

Look at: [explicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (number 2)

Comment: Look at number 2 in your link and **keep on reading**. This is not a valid C++ cast, and there is an example there that's very much like this code.

Comment: @Becker Ok, you are right I miss the two token issue.